# Crystal build fails with linker error

Tags: crystal-lang

I've just tried to run the simple HTTP server from the language documentation. The program fails with an error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: execution of command failed with code: 1: `cc -o "/home/rasmus/dev/crystal/projects/hello/.crystal/crystal-run-hello.tmp" "${@}"  -rdynamic  -lssl -levent -lrt -lpcl -lpcre -lgc -lpthread -ldl`
```

The program has been copy-pasted from [the documentation](http://crystal-lang.org/docs/overview/http_server.html).

I can confirm that the program did/does run on my guest machine, but not on my host. Both are Ubuntu 14.04.3 installs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was simply that the SSL libraries weren't installed. If you have the same problem you can simply run `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`. This should install everything needed to fix the error.